# What is the best way to copy a database schema to a different schema in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am looking for the most efficient way to copy an Oracle database schema to a new schema on different tablespace.

This is what I have tried:

1. Export the current instance by `expdp`
2. Import the instance by using  `impdp` with REMAP_SCHEMA and REMAP_TABLESPACE attributes.

Is this the best way to achieve the goal? I am on Oracle 11g.

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ efficient and simplest.

Comment: BYe efficient, do you mean the copy operation that takes the least amount of time; that is, the one that has the highest performance?  Or do you mean the one that takes the shortest amount of time to code?  Or the one that uses the least amount of memory?

Comment: By the time we figure all this out, you will have already performed your procedure that you described in your question, and your question will become irrelevant.

Comment: @Robert Harvey♦ Thank you. I will say the shortest time and effort to implement the clone. What i have of hand are not huge databases. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by best you mean the simplest way, i would also suggest you using the Copy function inside SQL Developer Tool. You can watch this video to get an example: [SQL Developer - Database Copy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkPM3avDFbI).
In practice, all you must do is, create another schema which would be used as your target one, create a connection with that schema and use the tool. It has various options which let you select what kind of objects and other stuff to do. Of course, the target schema which you are creating should be on the tablespace you want. This way you are not creating and moving any files, and the tool will provide you with a script used to make the copy, which you can save for later.

Comment: Thanks and that's the best. Also is there an alternative to this way, as in command line, when without an IDE?